# Вывод чисел с плавающей точкой в строковом виде

Tags: python, float

Имеется код:

```
import time , math
def timer(func , *args , **kwargs):
    start = time.time()
    func(*args , **kwargs)
    end = time.time()
    result = end - start
    return result


def log_version1(N):
    number1 = math.log( N , 3)
    return number1


def log_version2(N):
    number1 = math.log(N)
    return number1 / math.log(3.0)


print('{:20f}'.format(timer(log_version1 , 150)))
print('{:20f}'.format(timer(log_version2 , 150)))
```

При действии функции print выводятся нули, как бы я не менял форматирование . Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код слишком быстро выполняется поэтому у вас 0, а форматирование подправил:

```
import math
import time


def timer(func , *args , **kwargs):
    start = time.time()
    func(*args , **kwargs)
    end = time.time()
    result = end - start
    return result


def log_version1(N):
    time.sleep(0.1)

    number1 = math.log(N, 3)
    return number1


def log_version2(N):
    number1 = math.log(N)
    return number1 / math.log(3.0)


print('{:.20f}'.format(timer(log_version1, 150)))
print('{:.20f}'.format(timer(log_version2, 150)))
```

Результат:

```
0.10000586509704589844
0.00000000000000000000
```